# Are $D_{20}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism, dihedral-groups

> Are  $D_{20}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ isomorphic?

For $D_{20}$ I am using the notation $D_{2n}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{2}, \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ are additive groups.

I think not, and my justification is this: In group $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ we have 2 elements of order 2, namely, $(1,5) $ and $(0,5)$; while in $D_{20}$ there are 10 rotations and 10 flips, where each flip has order 2, therefore they are not isomorphic. Is that so?

Comment: also, $D_{20}$ is not abelian

Comment: You are correct that they are not isomorphic and the reasoning you gave holds up. Another approach that can be a very effective first port of call for trying to distinguish two groups of the same order is to consider whether they are abelian. You fairly easily see that one of these groups is abelian and the other is not.

Comment: Oh, they are both right. I didn't see it before, that had saved me a lot of work :( . Thank you

Comment: There's one more order-2 element in $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_{10}$, namely $(1, 0)$.  But this is still far fewer than the 11 order-2 elements in $D_{20}$ (10 flips and one 180-degree rotation).

Answer (score 2):

Since $\Bbb Z_{10}\times \Bbb Z_2$ is abelian
and  $D_{20}\cong \Bbb Z_{10}\rtimes \Bbb Z_2\cong\langle g,h\mid g^{10}, h^2, hg=g^{-1}h\rangle$ is not, the groups are not isomorphic.

Comment: It's hard too see why one would even ask the OP if they were even remotely well versed in the content of your answer. If one does not know $D_{20}$ and $\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_{10}$ are non-isomorphic then isn't it likely they don't know $D_{20}$ is non-abelian or its group presentation or possibly even basic theorems that present it as a semidirect product ?

Answer (score 0):

$D_{20}$ has exactly $10$ reflections but $\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_{10}$ has only $\it{three}$ elements of order $2$, namely $(0+2\Bbb Z,5+10\Bbb Z),(1+2\Bbb Z,5+10\Bbb Z),(1+2\Bbb Z,0+10\Bbb Z)$, and thus $\require{cancel} D_{20}\;\cancel{\approx}\;\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_{10}$.

Comment: Did you mean $10$ where you typed $20$?   And what about $(1,0)$?

Comment: @J.W. Tanner. No, I meant $20$. $D_{20}$ has $20$ refelections not $10$ if that's what you meant. Yes, $(1+2\Bbb Z,0+20\Bbb Z)$ is the third element of order $2$.

Comment: OP is "using the notation $D_{2n}$" and considering $\mathbb Z_{10}$, not $\mathbb Z_{20}$

Comment: @J.W. Tanner. OK, thanks. I take it $D_{2n}$ denotes the dihedral group of the regular $n$-gon.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner. Why ?